# jCarousel Lite + how to add pagination?

Tags: pagination, jcarousellite

I need pagination in jCarousel Lite. Also want pause on mouse over event. Can anybody help?

I'm using code from : http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "btnGo" variable.

Create an array of references to classes, one for each of your list items in the carousel. Then pass this when you make the carousel.

```
$j('#home_carousel .side').jCarouselLite({
    auto:       6000,
    speed:      750,
    visible:    1,
    btnGo:      ['.button1', '.button2', '.button3']
});
```

In that example the page has 3 divs on the page with id's of button1 - 3 and the carousel has 3 slides.